# Send Javascript array to PHP using Ajax (can't echo out the array from PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, ajax

I've a form with a simple button in it. When clicking on the button the function `delete_data()` is called. This function fills an array with data. I would like to send this array to PHP with Ajax.

**Problem**: When using the `event.preventDefault();` as you can see in my JavaScript code, the success alert messages is displayed ("OK") but i don't obtain the echo from my php script.

Could you correct my code bellow or tell me what is wrong? Thanks a lot!

**HTML CODE**

```
<form id="form" method="POST"> 
      <button type="button"id="delete" onclick="delete_data();" name="delete"><i class="fa fa-remove" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete Zone(s)</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript CODE**

```
function delete_data(){
        
        event.preventDefault();
        
        var checkedIds = $(".chk:checked").map(function() {
            return this.id;
        }).toArray();

        var Arr = JSON.stringify(checkedIds);
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./delete_measurement.php",
            data: {arr: Arr}, 
            cache: false,
            
            success: function(){
                alert("OK");
            }

        });
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
include_once("./conn.php");
    
if(isset($_POST['arr'])){ 
    
    $arr = json_decode($_POST['arr']); 
    echo $arr; //can't echo
    
}else{ 
    echo "Failed";
    
}
?>
```

Comment: If you trying to echo static string as `echo 'Hello world';` is it working? I mean, do you know if the problem in the `echo` or in the post var?

Comment: console.log Arr  above ajax and see if its outputting properly

Comment: @MrKhan yes it's outputting the json string properly with all the Id's inside

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the right page? check your page name and the one you passed.

Comment: @dWinder No, when i echo out "Hello World" in the php script instead of $arr, nothing changes, i can't see the echo

Comment: Try to write the `$arr` to file -> can be you never config your default output as screen. And add `flush();` at the end of the file just in case

Comment: @MrKhan Yes it is correct, checked it multiple times...

Comment: do this before $arr.   echo $_POST['arr']

Comment: @MrKhan No does not work, I think nothing can be echo out from my php script

Comment: if(isset($_POST['arr'])){ $arr = json_decode($_POST['arr']);

   echo $arr; //can't echo}else{ echo "failed"}Do this

Comment: @MrKhan Using the code you wrote, nothing happens. Not even the else statement..

Comment: @MrKhan Looks like the php script to get executed at all..

Comment: Are you using Xamp server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's logic that you don't see the echo. Add a parameter to the success function like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./delete_measurement.php",
        data: {arr: Arr}, 
        cache: false,
        
        success: function(data){
            // This will show what you echo in PHP (in the console)
            console.log(data)
            alert("OK");
        }

    });
```